# Kivy - How to detect if a button is pressed?

Tags: python, kivy

Ok so, I have an app where when you click a button and a popup appears. In the popup, you are able to schedule an event. When you click the 'Schedule' button, for now, I'd like it to print to the terminal that it has been clicked. I am trying to define a function in python and connect it with my id in my kv file for the button press to be recorded, but it doesn't seem to be working. Help? Might be an obvious answer, but I am still learning lol

**Python**

```
  def schedule_event(self, *args):
      if self.root.ids['set_event']:
          print('Working')
```

**Kv File**

```
<ButtonPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'Set Events'
    title_align: 'center'
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 200

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        TextInput:
            id: scheduled_event
            hint_text: "Something scheduled for this day..."

        BoxLayout:

            Button:
                id: set_event
                text: "Schedule"
                on_press: app.root.schedule_event()
                on_release: root.dismiss()

            Button:
                id: cancel
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Comment: on_press: module.func()

Comment: @CSMaverick My python function is not finding the kv file id

Comment: from kivy.app import App

Comment: your python file should have APP class and call the ButtonPopup@Popup

Comment: The `id` that you are trying to reference is only valid within the `ButtonPopup` class, so the `schedule_event()` method must be a method of the `ButtonPopup` class. And, just to be clear, `self.root.ids['set_event']` is a reference to the `Button` instance.

Comment: @CSMaverick That function I created is in my app class

Comment: @JohnAnderson How can I add the method to the ButtonPopup class ? Because I only have it in my kv file

Comment: I get an error `KeyError: 'set_event'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KeyError` means there is no `set_event` in your `App` root class `ids`, which is to be expected. In your `.py` file add:

```
class ButtonPopup(Popup):
    def schedule_event(self, *args):
        if 'set_event` in self.ids:
            print('Working')
        else:
            print('Missing set_event')
```

Then, in your `.kv` file, replace `<ButtonPopup@Popup>:` with `<ButtonPopup>:` This puts your method in the `ButtonPopup` class where it can easily access the `ids` of that class. Also, in your `.kv` file, change `on_press: app.root.schedule_event()` to `on_press: root.schedule_event()`

The `id` that you set in your `.kv` file will be in the `ButtonPopup` class, not in the `App`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids).

Comment: Ohh so basically if I want to add logic to my class it has to be created in with my app class in python, not with the `@` in the kv file. It works, thanks a bunch.

Comment: The `@` in the `.kv` file is used to create `Dynamic` classes, which are typically used to specify common properties of some Widgets that you will use. The `<ButtonPopup@Popup>:` is a `Dynamic` class rule that specifies what properties to set whenever you create a `ButtonPopup` instance in your `.kv` file. This is the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes) for `Dynamic` classes.